# Rendering variant does not render data if template is changed

Tags: sxa, presentation, templates

**Scenario:** I have a template that has shared fields, now I got the requirement to provide multilingual support in few components. I can't change the shared field because data should be shared in other components.

**What I did:** I have just duplicated existing the template, unchecked "Shared" checkbox and assigned this template to existing data.

**Problem** After changing the template, rendering variant stopped rendering the data. I could not see any dependency on the template, it is just a field name that should match field name of data and I did not rename any field.

We are not using scriban, variants are just created using traditional way.

Can someone please help on what I am missing here?

Comment: I think it is not the variant that is not showing your data anymore.. I think the data might be gone. Did you verify after changing the template of your items that the data is still in the fields? Also verify the web database (after publishing)

Comment: @Gatogordo data is there after changing the template

Comment: "assigned this template to existing data" means you have changed template at datasource item level? If yes, can you please try to duplicate the Rendering variant and assign it to a test page with the new template datasource to see it that works first or not?

Comment: If you can create and share the gif image or share some images that would be helpful to understand your problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Are we referring to clone of component, if yes then the template and the rendering template created are tied to rendering in SXA.

If you try to duplicate the template, the rendering doesn't associate to the duplicated template.

Hence the rendering Variant doesn't work with duplicate template but with actual template it works.

For multilingual site, language fallback is needed.

Hope this helps!

Thanks,
Yamini